# Apache IP based hosting solution shows apache test page and not the website

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, centos6

I am trying to setup my virtual server to host websites based on IP.
Currently I am trying to only setup 1 website and using only 1 IP.

/etc/httpd/conf.d/example.com.conf file contents:

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost xx.xxx.xx.xxx:80

<VirtualHost xx.xxx.xx.xxx:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/example.com/public
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/example.com/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/example.com/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I removed "Listen" and "NameVirtualHost" from httpd.conf and only using them in my example.com.conf files.

The problem that I'm having is that the apache test page kicks in and not the website but once I change the IP to "*" it works:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/example.com/public
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/example.com/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/example.com/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

UPDATE!!
The IP address that I am trying to use is not an internal network IP but an external (public) IP address. I have 3 public IP addresses pointing to this server.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: What happens if you put `listen ipaddr:80` into the config and restart with the vhost config being an IP address?

Comment: I tried putting in Listen for that IP address but after that it will fail to restart apache, error: (99)Cannot assign requested address: make_sock: could not bind to address xx.xxx.xx.xxx:80 no listening sockets available, shutting down

Comment: Since you mentioned it, do you *have* internal network IPs?  If you have something changing the IP address on the packet before it gets to your server, then apache won't know what the "public" IP address was, it will only see the internal IP.

Comment: Is this public IP address configured directly at your server?

Comment: Hi, I contacted the hosting provider and it is as @DerfK thought that the IP is just pointing (nat'd) to the server but the server doesn't know about it. They told us to use the internal virtual server IP and not the public IP. Thanks guys this is now resolved.

Comment: @DerfK post your comment as a reply  and I will accept it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have a firewall or some other device changing the IP on the packet from a public IP to a private IP, you will need to use the private IP in Apache's configuration for the `VirtualHost`.  Apache will only see the private IP, so it won't know what public IP was originally requested.

Answer (score 1):

Do you still have the `welcome.conf` that CentOS puts in the Apache conf directory?

There's no need for it once you start customising your Apache configuration and it acts as a default catch-all vhost.

Comment: Hi @Ladadada I tried removing the welcome.conf but all that does is showing the root of directory /var/www/sites that contains the folder example.com